# Git tag release build files and reset to commit without

Tags: bash, git

This is part of a library that wants to release builded files (eg `dist/*`) when published to npm and bower. However, I don't want to commit those builded files for obvious reasons. Bower uses tags, and so I need tag to hold a version that contains builded files.

I didn't think twice, and that's what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ '' == $1 ]] && echo "Please provide patch, minor, major argument" && exit 1

# build dist files
gulp
# use npm to get the next semver (ie npm version patch increments patch number)
# --no-git-tag-version is to avoid any git interactions
newver=$(npm --no-git-tag-version version $1)

# dist files are ignored, adding them with the updated package.json
git add -f dist package.json

# commit and tag the new version with dist files
git commit -m $newver
git tag $newver

# publish on npm
npm publish

# reset the latest commit
git reset --hard HEAD~1

# issue the npm command again so that package.json gets updated
newver=$(npm --no-git-tag-version version $1)

# only add the package.json, dist files are gone
git add package.json

# commit and push tags
git commit -m $newver
git push --tags
git push
```

I'm wondering if this would be considered as a bad-practice, if there is something I could improve, or if someone has a better idea on how to do this. It's working great, but is having a tag that refers to an overridden commit a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very nicely written script.

> It's working great, but is having a tag that refers to an overridden commit a good idea?

It doesn't sound great, but I don't have a better idea either.
In any case, I don't see any harm in doing this.
The content of these commits don't pollute the history because they are not really part of it.

<strike>If repository storage becomes a problem later,
you can always wipe out the obsolete tags.</strike>
(As you mentioned in a comment, this might not be such a good idea if package managers (like bower) rely on git tags for dependencies...)

#### Error handling

What if `gulp` fails? The script will happily go ahead and publish something broken or half-baked.
It would be good to add some error handling here, for example:

```
if ! gulp; then
    echo "Fatal: gulp failed, aborting..."
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Code duplication

This line appears twice:

> ```
> newver=$(npm --no-git-tag-version version $1)
> ```

As it's a non-trivial command,
it would be good to put it in a function, for example:

```
set_newver() {
    newver=$(npm --no-git-tag-version version $1)
}
```

#### Naming

It's good to give command line parameters a proper name early on,
and refer to them by that name throughout the script,
instead of a meaningless `$1`. For example `version`.

This may be subjective, but I find `newver` a bit awkward,
and perhaps `npm_version` would be better. I leave that up to you.

Comment: "you can always wipe out the obsolete tags"
This is not a good idea if package managers (like bower) rely on git tags for dependencies.

Comment: Hm, ok, I see your point... Scratched that out, and added your comment.